# Error: Update could not be validated. Make sure network secure and try again.

Tags: updates

Current version of Mamp Pro is 5.04 (15996). The available updates window says "Mamp 5.0.0 > 5.1. Update fails with a message saying Error: Update could not be validated. Please make sure you are using a secure network and try again."

Is it odd that the update does not say 5.0.4 > 5.1??
I have no idea what secure network is referred to. Everything on my computer is as secure as I can make it. Especially the wireless network.

I'm running High Sierra 10.13.6 on a new iMac.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue has affected other updates in the past. Not sure what the exact cause is, however, the workaround is straight forward.

1, [Download the latest version manually from MAMP here.](https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/)
2, Run the installer, closing MAMP beforehand.
3, Once restarted, the option to 'upgrade' will present itself, click install and it should work no problem.

**Edit:** Since 5.3 -> 5.4, there is no need for step 3. Just the first 2.

Comment: This has been driving me nuts! Your solution worked perfectly. Much appreciated.